R S7 classes: set object property inside method
I'm trying to use the R S7 package to create a class. I would like a method that operates on the class to be able to set its properties. However, all the examples I can find in the documentation get properties, but don't set them. In what I'm trying below it runs without an error, but the new name property I set doesn't seem to stick after the method has been run.
library(S7)

Dog <- new_class("Dog", properties = list(
  name = class_character
))
set_dog_name <- new_generic("set_dog_name", "x")
method(set_dog_name, Dog) <- function(x, new_name) {
  x@name <- new_name
  print(x@name) # This prints "Dot" as expected
}
dog <- Dog(name="Spot")
set_dog_name(dog, "Dot")
print(dog@name) # This prints "Spot", but I am expecting "Dot"

[1] "Dot"
[1] "Spot"


Shouldn't you assign the method return value dog <- set_dog_name(dog, "Dot") in order to make the change effective outside the function?

See the set_props() function
I believe the S7 package is designed intentionally to create copies of objects rather than modify. While this does have some performance implications (though because of copy-on-modify it's not as bad as it may seem), it also can make it easier to avoid bugs.
Here's a way to modify your code so it actually works (though you may want to change the method name).
library(S7)

Dog <- new_class("Dog", properties = list(
    name = class_character
))
set_dog_name <- new_generic("set_dog_name", "x")
method(set_dog_name, Dog) <- function(x, new_name) {
    x@name <- new_name
    print(x@name) # This prints "Dot" as expected
    x
}
dog <- Dog(name="Spot")
dog2 <- set_dog_name(dog, "Dot")
#> [1] "Dot"

dog
#> <Dog>
#>  @ name: chr "Spot"
dog2
#> <Dog>
#>  @ name: chr "Dot"

If you really need the behavior you describe, the R6 package can work this way. I don't think it's possible in the S7 package.
